# Angular 6 - Convert byte array into .docx

Tags: angular, ms-word, byte

I currently have a form that posts some data to my .NET core API. The API then generates a .docx file and sends this file back to my Angular 6 app in a byte array.

How can I convert this byte array to a docx and download it ready for the user to open it in my Angular app?

Have found a little on PDFs but nothing on word documents.

Here is my Angular service:

```
CreateDoc(data) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/CompletedFactFind/SaveAndGenerateCompletedFactFind`, data, this.options).pipe(map(response => {
        return response;
    }));
}
```

I'm getting the response which is the Byte array but no sure where to go from here.

Here is my my code that sends the doc as byte array from .net core api:

```
 var newFile2 = @"Documents/" + userId + "-FactFind-" + completedFactFind.Id + ".docx";
        using (var fs = new FileStream(newFile2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();


            var p0 = doc.CreateParagraph();
            p0.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.CENTER;
            XWPFRun r0 = p0.CreateRun();
            r0.FontFamily = "microsoft yahei";
            r0.FontSize = 18;
            r0.IsBold = true;
            r0.SetText("Fact Find");

            doc.Write(fs);



            // Convert and send document
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(newFile2);
            return new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/msword");
        }
```

I'm using the nuget package - NPOI to generate the document.

Any help would be great.

Comment: If you `console.log(response)`, what are you getting? I only ask because I'm not sure what format you're using to transmit a byte array over HTTP. Also, what is the `Content-Type` response header being set to?

Comment: check this https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js

Comment: Have updated my question with the .net code used to send the document to the client app. This includes the header.

Comment: @DBoi here the response you are getting as long string?

Comment: Yes and now i'm looking to convert that string of bytes to a word doc and make it downloadable. is this possible? Am I missing  a much more simple way of doing this?